# get a list of ALL resources types in your Azure tenant

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to use Azure Resource Graph to get ALL resources in my tenant. But for some reson i am not able to get blob, queue, table or files resources in a storage account. I get the storage account it self, but i also would like the child resources.

I know the resources exist in the tenant.
The query i send in the request ask to summarize the resource to only return one of each type with the same kind.

```
$Query = 'Resources | summarize any(id) by type, kind'

$RestSplat = @{
    Uri         = 'https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources?api-version=2020-04-01-preview'
    Method      = 'Post'
    Body        = @{
        query             = $Query
        managementGroupId = $ManagementGroupId
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    headers     = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $($AzToken.Token)" }
}

$resources = Invoke-RestMethod @RestSplat
```

if i can use something else then Azure Resource Graph i am very open to that. I just need to end up with a list with all resources types containing resource id, type and kind

```
foreach ($resourcesDataRow in $resources.data.rows) {
    $resourcesDataRows += [PSCustomObject]@{
        type   = $resourcesDataRow[0]
        kind   = "$($resourcesDataRow[1])"
        any_id = $resourcesDataRow[2]
    }
}

Write-Verbose "Getting all unique resources types and sort by type for tenant: $($AzToken.tenantId)"
$resourcesDataRows | Group-Object type | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] } | Sort-Object -Property type
```

Comment: Your current query will correctly return child resources, for example SQL Server and SQL Databases. See Derek's answer for why storage account details are not returned.

Answer (score 1):

Blob, queue, table or files objects are not technically Azure "resources" so they're not going to be found on the `management.azure.com` endpoint. Microsoft uses the terms "Control Plane" and "Data Plane" to refer to the distinctions you're talking about.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/control-plane-and-data-plane

If you want to fetch data plane objects in your script, you'll need to query for them explicitly, and that might get complicated because there are a lot of different types.